# object destroyed when return from the function

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, namespaces

I am working on qt project and have noticed that my application crashes .
 ON debugging I have found that its because of the qpushbutton objects not being created /initialised.

Now I cant understand why its not been initialised ?

I have written function in namespace which calls constructor for all Qpushbutton  and I am passing object by reference to the function 
so shouldn't it retain its value once function has returned? but in  my case as soon as function returns it is destroyed?
Is it  something to related with Namespace???

Any help or criticism will be helpful?

```
   MY_Utility.h
  class MY_Utility
  {

private:
    QPushButton* add_cal_button_; 
    QPushButton*  sub_cal_button_; 
    QPushButton*  mul_button_; 

  }
My_Utility.cpp

namespace
{
   void create_push_button_for_cal( QPushButton *button_cal, QString button_name, QGridLayout *grid, int grid_row, int grid_col )
    {
        button_cal = new QPushButton( button_name );

        if(!button_cal )
    {
        msg.setInformativeText("The code does not come here so object is created");
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText("Messsage");
        msg.setInformativeText("OBject not initialised in create_push button  ");
        msg.exec();;
    }
        button_cal->setFixedSize( 200 , 40 );
        button_cal->setVisible( false );
        grid->addWidget(  button_cal, grid_row, grid_col );
    }


    // function where we call all button created
void create_main_view( MY_Utility* main_p, QTreeWidget* tree_p, QTableWidget* table_p, QPushButton* add_cal_button_,  
                                                                                                   QPushButton* sub_cal_cal_button_, 
                                                                                                   QPushButton* mul_cal_button_,

{
    QWidget*        center_p = new QWidget( main_p );
    QHBoxLayout*    layout_p = new QHBoxLayout( center_p );
    QGridLayout*    grid     = new QGridLayout( center_p );
    grid->setSpacing( 1 );

    create_push_button_for_cal( add_cal_button_, "addition_calculate" , grid, 1, 2 );
    if( !add_cal_button_ )
    {
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText("Messsage");
        msg.setInformativeText("OBject not initialised in first part of message  why not ?? ");
        msg.exec();;
    }
    create_push_button_for_cal( sub_cal_cal_button_ ,"sub_Calculate",           grid, 2, 2 );
    create_push_button_for_cal( mul_cal_button_ ,    "multplication_Calculate", grid, 3, 2 );
    // Make the QWidget the central widget so we can resize within it
    main_p->setCentralWidget( center_p );
   bla .. 
   bla ..



}

}

My_Utility::set_all_cal_button_visible(){
 add_cal_button_->setVisible(true) ; // it crashes here 

}
```

Comment: your assumption of "not initialized" is most probably wrong. it it were right it would indicate some deeper & nastier problem like memory corruption.

Comment: @Alf ,  when i try to call teh Qpushbutton say add_cal_button in some member function of MY_Utility it crashes. example     My_Utility::set_all_cal_button_visible(){ add_cal_button_->setVisible(true) ;  // it crashes here }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a C++ problem, not a Qt problem.

```
void create_push_button_for_cal(QPushButton *button_cal, QString button_name)
{
    button_cal = new QPushButton(button_name);
    Q_ASSERT(button_cal);
}
```

The *pointer* (an address) is passed by value. Your code *discards* this value, and overwrites it with the pointer to the new instance.

The check for null `button_cal` is useless, since `new` holds a nice invariant: if the code that follows it executes, it means it has succeeded in allocating the memory. It makes life really simple: if `new` returns a value, it's fine. It won't return an invalid or null value.

If `new` fails, then the assert will not ever be executed, in fact, the `new` won't even return a value. It will throw an exception, and when that exception is thrown, there is very little that you can do since doing almost anything will require more memory, and we've just ran out :(

You need to change the signature of the function to return the pointer to the newly created instance. You should also pass Qt classes by const reference, not by value. And if the other code in the function could throw an exception, use a smart pointer to protect yourself from leaking the button instance. So:

```
QPushButton * create_push_button_for_cal(const QString & button_name) {
    QScopedPointer<QPushButton> btn(new QPushButton(button_name));
    ...
    // If any code here throws an exception, the scoped pointer will delete
    // the button instance, so that it won't leak.
    ...
    return btn.take();
}
```

Comment: Or change it like this
void create_push_button_for_cal(QPushButton *&button_cal, QString button_name)
This will create a reference to pointer.

Comment: @Sayutee Yeah, but that's just very bad style when all you have is logically a single returned value, and no use for the incoming value. It's better not to teach that.

Comment: Agreed. Sorry I didn't give much thought about design / style things before posting :)

Comment: @KubaOber, Thanks a lot mate, It was very helpful and I learned few nw things from you. Your detailed explanation is excellent